# Get full filename given half in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Is there a way to get the full file name of a file in shell if I know half of the filename.
For example, I know the file name starts with `stack`. Say the full name of the file if `stack-123.sh`, how do I get this full name in a variable?

Comment: I guess you need to use `find` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know the path of the directory containing the file and that only one file will match, then it should be sufficient to just use `echo`:

```
var=$(echo /path/to/dir/stack*)
```

This expand to the list of paths matching the glob, so if there are multiple files that match, then you'll need to change your approach.

Answer (score 0):

grep "stack"  -rnw .

Try this you will find easily.

Comment: This will search in the subfolders too. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Did you find the file?

Comment: This will search the _contents_ of files for `stack`, not their names.